# TinyMCE textarea doesn't respond to 'onkeydown' event

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'm trying to trigger a warning when the user leaves the page if he had made changes in the textareas of TinyMCE plugin.

There's my code. It works if i use a normal form textarea, but it doesn't go well when i add the 'onkeydown' event to the tiny's textarea. I've comproved the value of 'cambios' with the browser console and i saw that it never changes its value.

JS:

```
var cambios = false;

function change_cambios (){ cambios = true;}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(cambios) {
        return confirm('Are you sure?');
    }
    return;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <form id="formulari" method="post" >
        <textarea id="ap0sub2" name="area" onkeydown="change_cambios();"></textarea>
    </form>
```

That works perfectly if i use it within tinyMCE plugin. But when i include the text editor, the value of 'cambios' remains to false.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE hides the `textarea` and presents its own contenteditable `div` so there *is* no keydown happening on your textarea. You'll need to add the event listener using tinyMCE's methods when you initialise it:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   selector:'#ap0sub2',
   setup : function(ed) {
                  ed.on('keydown', function(e) {
                     cambios = true;
                     console.log(cambios);
                  });
            }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/exmdg7ha/

Comment: Oh, that's great! I didn't know that i can add event listeners in editor methods. Thanks a lot, now I can do a lot of things that I thought I can't :)

Answer (score 1):

In tinyMce 4:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.on('keyDown', function (e) {
            console.log('Element clicked:', e.target.nodeName);
        });
    }
});
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/